# With Sinon, how can I mocked http.foo.get when http is a property?

Tags: javascript, mocking, sinon

I have a file I wish to test, with an `http-client` that should be mocked:

`schema.js`:

```
const { http } = require('@foo/http-client');
.......
const result = await http.foo('another-service').get('graphql', {
                query: `
    {
        SomeResolver(clientId: "${args.clientId}") {
            id
            start
            end
        }
    }
    `,
});
```

I need to mock the `result`.

`schema.test.js`:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const mockHttp = sinon.mock(require('@foo/http-client'));
.........
mockHttp.expects('foo').returns({
    get: (x,y) => {
        // mock the response here
    },
});
```

`TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property foo as function` is the error with the above which makes sense because `http` is `destructured`.

However, if I change the `expects` line to:

```
mockHttp.expects('http').returns
```

I get the error `TypeError: Attempted to wrap object property http as function` which also makes sense because `http` is a `property`.

As you can see I'm quite new to `Sinon` but my question is how can I mocked `http.foo.get` when `http` is a `property`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, mocks are for objects, and expectations are for functions - one per each.

In your context, it seems you could do:

```js
const { http } = require('@foo/http-client');
const mockHttp = sinon.mock(require('@foo/http-client').http); // mind .http
mockHttp.expects('foo').returns({
    get: (x,y) => {
        // mock the response here
    },
});
http.foo().get();
mockHttp.verify();
```

If you need to set expectations on other `http` functions, you can reuse `mockHttp`. If you need expectations on functions somewhere else in the module, you'll need to create another mock for the object they're declared in, and `verify()` that other mock as well. (That's how I understand it anyway, someone please correct if you know better!)

In any case, using destructuring assignments won't change the fact that your `http` variable *references* the module's `http` property. In other words:

```js
const { http } = require('@foo/http-client');
console.log( http === require('@foo/http-client').http ); // true
```

Comment: Thanks. Away from my machine for a few hours but I'll check that later.